# Updating the script present in Poky Source code

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

meta/recipes-core/initrdscripts/files/init-install-efi.sh is used for formatting and creating partitions.

I have modified this file to create one more partition for software update.

Can I copy the newly updated script file in my own custom layer recipes-core/initrdscripts/files/init-install-efi.sh.

Will it update the init-install-efi.sh. If not how to achieve this, I don't want to touch the poky source code, as that is fetched using repo utility

```
$ tree meta-ncr/
meta-ncr/
├── conf
│   ├── bblayers.conf
│   ├── layer.conf
│   └── machine
│       └── panther2.conf
├── recipes-core
│   └── initrdscripts
│       ├── files
│       │   └── init-install-efi.sh
│       └── initramfs-live-install-efi_1.0.bbappend
└── scripts
    └── setup-environment


$ cat meta-ncr/recipes-core/initrdscripts/initramfs-live-install-efi_1.0.bbappend 
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"  
SRC_URI = "file://init-install-efi.sh"
```

After debugging, I found that it is copying the script present in the meta-intel layer and not of my layer.

This is from the output of `bitbake-layers show-appends`

```
initramfs-live-install-efi_1.0.bb:
  /home/jamal/repo_test/sources/meta-intel/recipes-core/initrdscripts/initramfs-live-install-efi_%.bbappend
  /home/jamal/repo_test/sources/meta-ncr/recipes-core/initrdscripts/initramfs-live-install-efi_1.0.bbappend
```

Can you please tell me what changes are required for my bbappend to work instead of meta-intel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yocto provides *bbappend* mechanism to archive Your case without touching metadata from *poky*, please follow these few steps to archive this:

1. create new layer or use Your existing one,
2. in this layer create *bbappend* file for *initramfs-module-install-efi_1.0.bb* or *initramfs-live-install-efi_1.0.bb* (I found that this recipes are based on this script), with content:

   ```
   $ cat meta-test/recipes-core/initrdscripts/initramfs-live-install-efi_1.0.bbappend
   FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"  
   SRC_URI = "file://init-install-efi.sh"
   ```
3. move modified script file under *files* directory, Your meta layer structure should look like:

   ```
   $ tree meta-test/
   meta-test/
   ├── conf
   │   └── layer.conf
   ├── COPYING.MIT
   ├── README
   └── recipes-core
       └── initrdscripts
           ├── files
           │   └── init-install-efi.sh
           └── initramfs-live-install-efi_1.0.bbappend
   ```

   4 directories, 5 files

Then finally after running *do_unpack* task on *initramfs-live-install-efi* recipe in working directory You will find Your modified file in recipe workspace,

```
    $ bitbake -c unpack initramfs-live-install-efi
```

Test:

```
    $ cat tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/initramfs-live-install-efi/1.0-r1/init-install-efi.sh 
    #!/bin/bash

    echo "hello"
```

[FILESEXTRAPATHS](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-FILESEXTRAPATHS) - is used to extend search path for *do_fetch* and *do_patch* tasks.

Comment: I did as you said, after unpacking it still has the old file

Comment: I have add tree of my layer and contents of bbappend file

Comment: One thing, did You layer with bbappend file is added into belayers.conf file ?

Comment: bitbake show-layers displays the bbappend file, but unpacking shows the old script.. Need to investigate

Comment: Do you any debugging techniques for this to debug.. I mean in Yocto

Comment: Look at the question, I have updated it.. Debugging found, there is a bbappend file present in the meta-intel, which is causing the problem, it is not copying from my layer instead of meta-intel.. Can we switch the priorities